# How can I identify the failed command, when using make -j

Tags: gnu-make

When using `make -j` on a file with many targets and one of then fails, it can be a bit of a pain to identify the particular command that provoked the error. Especially when there's at lot of output.

Can I persuade gnu make to print something like this (preferably at the end of output):

```
This particular command failed: "frobniz -foo" with output "frobniz only takes -foo options on a thursday"?
```

For now, I resort to using `make -j -Otarget`  inside tmux with its searchable history so that I can locate that "failed" output:

```
Makefile:41: recipe for target 't4' failed
```

Alas, the 't4' target has about 40 commands with plenty output so I have to do more searching in order to locate the actual command that fails. It's manageable, but does feel clumsy.
I tried `remake`too, but it does not seem to have any options for this.

EDIT: Obviously, I should have put some code here, let me amend that; This is one target out of 16, each with about 40 commands. Example Below have been cut to 4 commands.

```
t4:
  sso -dump FAIL:B -path /instadm-bin/ktkopdat.start -ttarget "AA" ht1
  sso -dump FAIL:B -path /instadm-bin/ktknyadm -ttarget "BB" ht1
  sso -dump FAIL:B -path /instadm-bin/multiadm -ttarget "CC" ht1
  sso -dump FAIL:B -path /instadm-bin/ktkslet.start -ttarge "DD" ht1
```

Lets say I run `make -j` and the second line above fails. The failure and the command are visible in the output from make, but mixed in with a lot of other output.

What make executes to generete the error is: `sso -dump FAIL:B -path /instadm-bin/ktknyadm -ttarget "BB" ht1` - it fails with a status -1.

Now, make must know which command failed, since it is able to abort the process at this point. This information is very valuable to me, but it is nevertheless hidden in a jumble of output from a lot of parallel processes. Please note that I could of course rerun make without the `-j` option, thus ensuring that the needed info shows up at the bottom of the output, but I'd rather not repeat the lengthy build more times than necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by *40 commands with plenty of output*.  It would be helpful if you provided an example.

If you mean, you have 40 logical recipe lines (not using backslash to combine 40 physical lines into a single logical line), then as soon as one of those commands fails make will stop building that recipe and won't run any more commands, so the failed command will always be the last one.

If you mean, you have a long shell script that consists of 40 physical lines combined into a single logical line using semicolons and backslashes, then make cannot help you, because make has no idea what command failed.

Make will invoke one instance of the shell and pass each entire logical recipe line to that shell, and wait for the shell to exit with an exit code of 0 or not-0.  If the exit code is 0 then make assumes the recipe succeeded; if the exit code is non-0 make assumes the recipe failed.  Make has no way to know that there was more than one command invoked, which commands were invoked, which ones may have failed, which ones emitted which output, etc.  All of that information is known only to the shell, not to make.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I've edited to clarify.
I meant 40 logical recipe lines and as you mention, the failing one will halt the make of that particular target. But there are plenty other targets being executed at the time (on account of the `-j`option) so the failed command will rarely snow at the bottom.

Comment: Using `-O` is the only thing that can help you make this simpler, by keeping the output and the command together.  You'll still have to go back through the output to find the failed command.  There's no facility in GNU make that would "summarize" failures at the end of the run.  Note that make currently has no way of preserving the output of the command: it doesn't generally store command output.  A new feature could be added to preserve error output if `-O` was used.